# Getting typeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value in rendering for compostion api setup hook - vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In my vue 3 application, i am creating a functional component using composition api. In this setup hook, i am passing data reactive object for style and class. After running the application, i am getting this type error.

Here is my setup function:

```
setup(props, context) {
   const data = reactive({
      style: {},
      class: []
   });
   let moreIcons = {};
   
    let cColor ='';
     if (props.primary||props.prim) { cColor= 'primary'; }
     else if (props.point||props.pnt) { cColor= 'point'; }
     else if (props.default||props.dft) { cColor= 'default'; }
     else if (!!props.color||!!props.col) { cColor= props.color||props.col; }

    let cSize = '' ;
     if(props.large || props.lg) {cSize= 'large';}
     else if(props.medium || props.md) {cSize= 'medium';}
     else if(props.small || props.sm) {cSize= 'small';}
     else if(props.xsmall || props.xs) {cSize= 'xsmall';}
     else if(props.full) {cSize= 'full';} 

    let customSize = props.iconSize || props.size;
     if(parseInt(customSize, 10)) {customSize = customSize + 'px';}
    let iconName = props.icon || context.slots.default().text;
    let options = {
        class: [
            'ur-icon',
            'ur-icon--'+cType,
            cColor && 'ur-icon--'+cColor,
            cSize &&'ur-icon--'+cSize,
            props.spacing && 'ur-icon--spacing'
        ],
        style: {
            fontSize: customSize
        },
        on: context.emit('click') // **getting error because of this**
    };
    
    if(data.class) {
        if(Array.isArray(data.class)) {
            options.class = options.class.concat(data.class);
        }
        if(typeof data.class === 'string' || typeof data.class === 'object') {
            options.class.push(data.class);
        }
    }
    if(data.style) {
        options.style = Object.assign(data.style, options.style);
    }
    if (moreIcons[iconName] !== undefined) {
        options.class.push('more-icon__'+iconName);
        let svg = moreIcons[iconName];
        if(!props.focusable) {svg = svg.replace('<svg ','<svg focusable="false" ');}
        options.domProps={innerHTML:svg};
    } else {
        // 1. icon class
        options.class.push('fa-'+iconName);
        // 2. type class
        if     ( props.brand )   { options.class.push('fab'); }
        else if( props.fab)      { options.class.push('fab'); }
        else if( props.regular ) { options.class.push('far'); }
        else if( props.far )     { options.class.push('far'); }
        else if( props.light)    { options.class.push('fal'); }
        else if( props.fal)      { options.class.push('fal'); }
        else if( props.old)      { options.class.push('fa'); }
        else if( props.fa)       { options.class.push('fa'); }
        else { options.class.push("fas"); }
    }
    return () => h('i',Object.assign(data, options));
}
```

After running the application, i am getting error(**typeError:Cannot convert object to primitive value**) because of 'on' event listeners. I have commented that error line in code. I am not able to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: What error exactly? Where does it occur? You omitted the most important information, it likely contains the exact place where it occurs, while the question requires to proofread the whole code

Comment: Yes ... Thanks for your response. I have updated question.